# How to trigger text-overflow: ellipsis on multi-line element

Tags: ellipsis, css

I have this element that contains a string which exceeds the space available. Text should be displayed on two lines only. I need `text-overflow: ellipsis` to be triggered but it's not happening here. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div><span>IpsumLorem Traborditum orb Porfalohyrm</span></div>
```

```css
div{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 8px 6px 6px;
    height: 44px;
    width: 133px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHge3/)

Answer (score -2):

You need `white-space: nowrap;` for `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to work properly:
http://jsfiddle.net/DHge3/3/

Comment: OP try to display text in Two lines, not in a single line as your Fiddle show it in a single line.

Answer (score -2):

Remove `padding` from your `CSS` and it will work fine

**CSS**

```
div {
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 44px;
    width: 133px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sxk8n/26/)**

Comment: No ellipsis displayed.

Comment: i don't think that the requirement is for Ellipse??