# How to make text-overflow ellipsis work on multi-line text?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I make `text-overflow: ellipsis` work in multi-line text without applying `white-space: nowrap`, with pure javascript, without including any jQuery library and without specifying the number of lines?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572330/is-it-possible-to-use-text-overflowellipsis-on-multiline-text, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222616/with-css-use-for-overflowed-block-of-multi-lines, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448511/pure-css-ellipsis-for-three-or-more-lines-of-text, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499108/css-multi-line-ellipsis-cross-browser, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596777/how-to-trigger-text-overflow-ellipsis-on-multi-line-element, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909489/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-on-two-lines-is-it-possible, and others.

Answer (score 1):

I made alot of search for this and I couldn't find any simple and pure Javascript solution. So I ended up making my own :

```
function ellipsis(el){
    var elheight =  el.offsetHeight;
    var eltxt = el.innerHTML;
    while (elheight < el.scrollHeight){
        eltxt = eltxt.substring(0, eltxt.length - 1);
        el.innerHTML = eltxt + '...';
    }
}
```

`elheight` contains the actual height of the box (using `offsetHeight`)

`scrollHeight` gives us the height of the content of the box (including the overflowing text)

This function stores the content of the box inside `eltxt` and then keep checking if the actual size of the box is still smaller than its content, and each time it removes 1 character from `eltxt` and replace the content of the element by the new value of `eltxt` plus the three points.

It works on Google chrome **4+**, IE **8+**, Firefox **3+**, Safari **4+**, and (I think) **all** Opera versions.

It's pretty simple and easy, but all I found on google is other long jQuery libraries with functions that you need to provide the number of lines you want in order for them to work etc..

**EDIT**

However, this solution is **NOT** the exact equivalent of `text-overflow: ellipsis` as it doesn't hide the extra text, it removes it. So if your box has got some animations and its dimensions are supposed to change (get wider for example) then your text will not reappear as it was. In that case I recommend storing the text of the box outside of the function and then you run the function each time the dimensions of the box change by giving it the text of the box as 2nd parameter :

```
var myElementsText = myElement.innerHTML;
function ellipsis(el, txt){
    var elheight =  el.offsetHeight;
    var eltxt = txt;
    while (elheight < el.scrollHeight){
        eltxt = eltxt.substring(0, eltxt.length - 1);
        el.innerHTML = eltxt + '...';
    }
}
function changeSize(el){
    el.ClassName = 'new_class_with_different_dimensions';
    function ellipsis(el, myElementsText);
}
```

Now if you run

```
changeSize(myElement);
```

The box will have its original text with the new ellipsis.